# How to display source code in flutter web?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I want to display this source code in flutter web.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      top: true,
      bottom: true,
      child: Scaffold(
        body: bodyView(),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: You want to display Dart code in flutter web? Could you clarify your question and what you have tried?

Comment: I want to display any type of code in web using flutter.

Comment: What have you tried? What's preventing you from doing that?

Comment: I don't know how do this that's why i am asking.

Comment: Just copy the code into a string and display the string.

Comment: can you share some demo code?

Comment: There are plenty of examples online in how to show text in flutter with the `Text` widget. I suggest you do that first.

Comment: I know how to show text in Text widget but i want how to show source code in web like html page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218532/discussion-between-christopher-moore-and-vinit-yadav).

Comment: doesn't the flutter inspector help?

Comment: You cant. Flutter compiles the code to the native html, css and stuff like that for flutter web.

Answer (score 5):

You could use the package [flutter_markdown](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_markdown) it supports the backtick quotes to show formatted code. The package's example file has an example with dart code.

**Code example:**

````dart
const String _markdownData = """
## Code blocks
Formatted Dart code looks really pretty too:
    ```
    void main() {
      runApp(MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
          body: Markdown(data: markdownData),
        ),
      ));
    }
    ```
""";

class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final controller = ScrollController();

    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Markdown(
          controller: controller,
          selectable: true,
          data: _markdownData,
          imageDirectory: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com',
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
````

**Image**

[image]

Comment: for code blocks, there should be no spaces!

https://www.markdownguide.org/extended-syntax/#fenced-code-blocks