# Format and Display html code snippet in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am developing an app using FLUTTER where I am giving a HTML tutorial in the form of text and as part of it, I want to display html code snippet in a correct format on my screen. Any help will be appreciated.

```
import 'package:flutter_highlight/flutter_highlight.dart';

HighlightView(
      code(),
      language: 'html',
    );
```

I have tried using flutter_highlight package but it displays the text as exactly as the text we give it. But I will get the code snippet from server as a single String and I want to format it before I give it to `HighlightView()`.

Comment: "*it displays the text as exactly as the text we give it*" - What do you mean with this? Does this mean the HTML gets parsed or that you actually see the HTML code?

Comment: that means, If I give the html code snippet by joining all the tags in a single line it displays exactly without formatting it

Answer (score 0):

You could use the package [flutter_markdown](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_markdown) it supports the backtick quotes to show formatted code.

Code example:

````
const String _markdownData = """
## Code blocks
Formatted Dart code looks really pretty too:
    ```
    void main() {
      runApp(MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
          body: Markdown(data: markdownData),
        ),
      ));
    }
    ```
""";

class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final controller = ScrollController();

    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Markdown(
          controller: controller,
          selectable: true,
          data: _markdownData,
          imageDirectory: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com',
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
````

I hope this helps you. Happy learning...

Reference: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63076095/how-to-display-source-code-in-flutter-web)

Comment: Nope, I want to display html code snippet without interpreting html code

Comment: @shaikshaheera do you want to show code snippet on UI directly?

Comment: yes exactly, I want to format the html code first and then show code snippet on UI directly.

Comment: @shaikshaheera I have update answer, please check it out.

Comment: not working for html

Comment: @shaikshaheera please share your implementations, so I could help you out.